# Swift macOS animating two NSTextViews

Tags: swift, macos, animation

I want to animate two textviews, TV1 is on screen and TV2 is offscreen. When a user clicks a button TV1 should reduce its size to 1/2 and TV2 should move from offscreen to lower half of the parent view.

I have this code but only the first view is being animated:

```
func toggleFrames() {
        
        var frame1H = self.view.frame.size.height
        var frame2H = CGFloat(0.0)
        var frame2Y = CGFloat(0.0)
        var txtV1Frame = txtContents.frame
        var txtV2Frame = txtChanges.frame
                
        if bViewingChanges {
            frame1H = frame1H/2
            frame2Y = (self.view.frame.size.height/2) - 10.0
            frame2H = frame1H
        }
        
        txtV1Frame.size.height = frame1H
        txtV2Frame.size.height = frame2H
        txtV2Frame.origin.y = 550.0
        
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({_ in
            NSAnimationContext.current.duration = 0.5
            txtContents.animator().frame =  txtV1Frame //reduce size of text view 1
            txtChanges.animator().frame = txtV2Frame //<--Grumble, not doing anything
        }, completionHandler:{
            print("Done animation") 
        })
        
    }
```

Comment: Are the text views inside scroll views? Is `txtV2Frame` what it should be?

Comment: Yes, both text views are within scroll views. txtV2Frame is correct.

Comment: Are `txtContents` and `txtChanges` text views or scroll views.